# PointLight affecting only one model, and not all the scene

Tags: three.js

I placed some pointLights in my scene and added some walls (exported from blender)(maze type) and a floor and ceiling (both exported from blender the same way as walls, and coded in three.js the same way as walls); the problem is that the lights affects only the walls, the ceiling is black without any light. Am I missing something? Can someone explain why I got that strange behaviour?

Thx for the answer, but the problem don't lays on doubleside (or maybe I'm setting it wrongly). This is the code of ceiling and floor, maybe can be of some help to figure out what the problem is (the ceiling is black and has no evidence of any existing source light, and the floor is texturized all with the same light, as if there was an ambientLight): [on the other hand, the lighting on walls works fine, well sort of, light positions are a bit messed but it works, so I deal with later]

```
function initCeiling () {
    var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
    loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;
    loader.load( 'models/ceiling.dae', function ( collada ) {
        var colladaCeiling = collada.scene.children[0]
        colladaCeiling.name = "ceiling";
        colladaCeiling.material.needsUpdate = true;
        colladaCeiling.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
        colladaCeiling.material.wireframe = false;
        colladaCeiling.position.set(0,2.5,0);
        colladaCeiling.scale.set(2,2,2);
        scene.add( colladaCeiling );
        } );
    }

function initFloor () {
    var floorTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'textures/floor.jpg' );
    floorTexture.wrapS = floorTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping; 
    var floorMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: floorTexture, side: THREE.DoubleSide } );
    var floorGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 45, 44.5 );
    var floor = new THREE.Mesh( floorGeometry, floorMaterial );
    floor.position.x = 6;
    floor.position.y = -2;
    floor.position.z = -22.25;
    floor.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
    scene.add( floor );
    }
```

Comment: to Skatox, spencer7593, RyPeck: you can only criticize others? I'm not dumb, I understand that my aswer wasn't supposed to be there already after the first comment (Joel's). Instead of helping (since that's the purpose of StackOwerflow) you just wanted to criticize and do nothing constructive. People like you should be banned from this kind of sites

Answer (score 0):

Surfaces in three.js (and webgl) are not double-sided by default. So you have to be careful about where and how you place the lights in the scene. But also to note, the more lights you place in the scene the longer it takes to render.

Having said that you either change the surfaces of your model to be double sided (easily done by adding `side: THREE.DoubleSide` to your material) or you add more lights in the scene.